# STM32F7: How to store one cycle of sinewave (1kHz) in array as PCM data?

Tags: stm32, digital-audio, pcm

I'm using a [STM32F746 discovery board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html) to learn about digital audio. I'm doing the basics right now. I want to store a single cycle of a 1kHz sinewave in an array and eventually use a DMA to transfer it to the audio codec ([WM8994](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8994_Rev4.6.pdf)) on the board in a continuous mode as to generate a 1kHz tone on the speaker output of the codec. This would be using I2S on the STM32.

I'm using an excel formula to generate the data. I get the data and plot it just fine. But the values I get are floating numbers. Here is a picture of the values from the positive peak. BTW the amplitude to 3 is because of the supply voltage on the codec is 3.3v:

[image: Sine wave 1kHz cycle]

I read in various places that PCM data is unsigned for 8 bits and signed for 16,24 and 32 bits. I have the option for selecting the "word length" in the codec so I'm thinking 16-bit. The data was generated with 48kHz as the sampling rate. So now I need an array of int_16 to fit my ... floating point values? I'm not sure how to do that and I also read about little endian ... not sure if I need to do that either. Could someone enlighten me please? Thanks.

Comment: you need to store  only 1/4 cycle

Comment: You can do this all in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Undo the multiplication by 3 and multiply with the largest amplitude that fits a signed 16-bit integer, 32767, and round up/down to nearest integer.

Your approach is a valid for testing and hobby use, but for any professional purpose, looping 48 samples over and over is generally not used as there are only 25 different steps.

Your calculations also have some errors in them, because the rising sine wave samples are not equal to falling sine wave samples.